# freedom of choice of 1-form in canonical representation of generic local field corresponds to gauge choice?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, hamiltonian-formalism, poisson-brackets

So it is a question in Gravitation Wheeler, Thorne and Misner 4.2 Exercise. Given F=$dp_{i}\wedge dq^{i}$. Using [canonical transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation) from p to $\bar{p}$ and q to $\bar{q}$, one gets $\bar{F}$=$d\bar{p_{i}}\wedge d\bar{q^{i}}$. Is this related to gauge choice? It looks like field content is not changed so it has to be gauge choice. If so, how can one relate this transformation to gauge choice? Does this transformation choose a gauge?

Comment: Let me suggest something for future questions (and for your current questions): if your question title is "A question about ..." then that's not a very good title. It's much better to put a short statement of the actual question you want to ask in the title field.

Comment: @David Z's above good suggestion is also discussed in [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/1000/2451) meta post.